# Stream (Geo)JSON file and get startByte and endByte of each JSON record in the file

Tags: node.js, json, stream, buffer, geojson

For very large JSON/GeoJSON files, I'd like to create a primitive key/value store that keeps track of the starting positions and lengths of each JSON record in the file. This way, I could look up individual records at a later stage without reading the whole file into memory (Using the [fd.read](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadbuffer-offset-length-position) API). Somewhat similar to a super simple database, but read-only and without the extra overhead.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't know how I could determine the starting position and byte length of each JSON record / GeoJSON feature in the original file.

Here's some pseudo-code showcasing what I'm trying to achieve, note that the `geojsonStream.parse` callback doesn't receive the `startByte` and `length` arguments in reality though.

Thanks for your help, also happy about any feedback outlining why this might be a bad idea :)

```js
import geojsonStream from 'geojson-stream'
import { open } from 'fs/promises'
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

function getFeaturePositionsInFile(fd) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const featurePositionsInFile = []
    const stream = fd
      .createReadStream()
      .pipe(geojsonStream.parse((building, index, startByte, length) => {
          // The startByte and length callback arguments are not real unfortunately :(
          featurePositionsInFile.push({
            index,
            startPosition,
            length
          })
      }))
     stream.on('end', () => resolve(featurePositionsInFile))
     stream.on('error', () => reject)
  })
}

function readSingleFeatureFromFile(fd, startPosition, length) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const buff = Buffer.alloc(length)
      const offset = 0
      const { buffer } = await fd.read(buff, offset, length, startPosition)
      const singleFeature = JSON.parse(buffer.toString())
      resolve(singleFeature)
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  })
}

const fd = await open('buildings.geojson')
const featurePositionsInFile = await getFeaturePositionsInFile(fd)
const featureIndexToRead = 0
const { startPosition, length } = featurePositionsInFile[featureIndexToRead]
const singleFeature = await readSingleFeatureFromFile(fd, startPosition, length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since I couldn't find a suitable package for my needs, I created a simple (naïve) solution using RegExp to extract single GeoJSON features.

It works given:

- The GeoJSON has a `properties` object, and the object is the last key in the parent GeoJSON object
- the GeoJSON (properties) solely consists ASCII characters

For GeoJSON files containing non-ASCII characters, the byte counting is off. I tried but couldn't really find out what exactly I'm doing wrong, so any help is appreciated!

For a more general solution, I guess one would need to implement the byte counting logic in an existing library such as [stream-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json)

```js
import { open } from 'fs/promises'
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

const HIGHWATERMARK = 64 * 1024 / 8

function getFeaturePositionsInFile(fd) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const featurePositionsInFile = []
    const stream = fd.createReadStream({highWaterMark: HIGHWATERMARK, autoClose: false});
    // this RegEx will solely work with standard GeoJSON without any foreign members:
    // https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-6.1
    // The properties object has to be present, and has to be that last key in the GeoJSON object
    const jsonExtractor = /\{[\n\r\s]*?"type":[\n\r\s]*?"Feature"[\S\s]*?\}(?:[\n\r\s]*\})+/g

    let string = ''
    let endPos = 0
    
    stream.on('data', (d) => {
      const section = d.toString()      
      const sectionLength = (new TextEncoder().encode(section)).length
      string += section
      endPos+= sectionLength
      
      let match
      let latestEndPositionInString = 0
      while ((match = jsonExtractor.exec(string)) != null) {
        const startPositionInString = match.index
        const featureString = match[0]
        const endPositionInString = startPositionInString + featureString.length
        const curStringLength = (new TextEncoder().encode(string)).length
        // calculate starting position in file
        const startPosition = endPos - curStringLength + startPositionInString
        // calculate number of bytes in feature
        const byteLength = (new TextEncoder().encode(featureString)).length
        // store info for later in our lookup array
        featurePositionsInFile.push({
          startPosition,
          byteLength
        })        
        if (endPositionInString > latestEndPositionInString) {
          latestEndPositionInString = endPositionInString
        }
      }
      // remove features from string to free memory
      string = string.substring(latestEndPositionInString)
    })
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(featurePositionsInFile))
    stream.on('error', () => reject)
  })
}

function readSingleFeatureFromFile(fd, startPosition, length) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const buff = Buffer.alloc(length)
      const offset = 0
      const { buffer } = await fd.read(buff, offset, length, startPosition)
      const featureString = buffer.toString()
      const singleFeature = JSON.parse(featureString)
      resolve(singleFeature)
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  })
}

async function getFeature(featureIndexToRead, featurePositionsInFile) {
  const { startPosition, byteLength } = featurePositionsInFile[featureIndexToRead]  
  const singleFeature = await readSingleFeatureFromFile(fd, startPosition, byteLength)
  return singleFeature
}

// source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-geojson/geojson-stream/master/test/data/featurecollection.geojson
const path = 'featurecollection.geojson'
// -> has 3 features

const fd = await open(path, 'r');
const featurePositionsInFile = await getFeaturePositionsInFile(fd)
// get nth (e.g 3rd) feature in file
const firstFeature = await getFeature(2, featurePositionsInFile)
console.log(firstFeature)

// done! make sure to close the filehandle
fd.close()
```

https://gist.github.com/chrispahm/c226cca151b25147869288600151a5f8